# Solving an integral using Leibnitz rule

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to solve the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(a + b \sin x)}{(a - b \sin x) \sin x} dx$$ using Leibnitz's rule of differentiating under the integral sign? If so, how? I've tried differentiating with respect to 'a' it but instead of simplification, only further complication is achieved. So many things that could be done turn up after the differentiation. 
And Wolframalpha says the integral does not converge though its supposed answer is $\pi \arcsin(b/a)$

Comment: Yes I'm sure about that.

Comment: @coffeemath I just tried wolfram alpha.  (a-bsin(x)) in numerator and denominator doesn't converge. neither does (a+bsin(x))

Comment: actually I believe wolfram alpha isn't handling the variables a and b well. Someone try with constant values?

Comment: "Solving" is the wrong word here.  It seems to be one of several catch-all terms used by people who don't know what word to use.  "When in doubt, use the word 'solve'." seems to be the operative rule.  In correct usage, one solves equations; one solves problems; one does not solve expressions.  One may _evaluate_ expressions or do various other things with them.

Comment: The integral is divergent with a=b=1, a=2 & b=1, a=5 & b=3. No combination seems to work.

Comment: Maybe you could add a source for the supposed value $\pi \arcsin (b/a).$ There may be some conditions on $a,b$ there.

Comment: Surprizingly, the antiderivative exists. It is just a monster but the integral cannot be computed.

Comment: I believe the integrand here is not written correctly, and the sine factor in the denominator should be really the denominator of a fraction of two sine terms, with the log taken of that fraction. [see answer below]

Comment: Using the adjusted form from my answer, I just tried a numerical case $p=2,q=1$ (So your $a=2,b=1$) and both sides came out $1.64493$. My software integrator didn't work for getting the exact value however.

Comment: @soft I found that something comes out of Leibniz differentiation, see added part to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's "Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products", 1980 edition, page 595 formula 4.441 (2), there is a formula
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \frac{p+q \sin ax}{p-q \sin ax} \frac{dx}{\sin ax}=\pi \arcsin \frac{q}{p},$$
with the restriction $p>q>0.$ The restriction is natural for the arcsine to exist on the right side, and maybe $p>q$ indicates the formula has some problem when $p=q.$ Also note the independence of the result on the multiplier $a,$ in particular taking $a=1$ the integrand here "almost" matches yours [replacing your $a,b$ by $p,q$ to align the constants]. But a crucial difference is that the factor $(p-q \sin ax)$ does not, as in your integral, occur as a factor of the denominator of the entire integrand, but rather it appears as the denominator of the quotient to which $\ln$ is applied. Given the matching of all other aspects of the formula, I'd have to guess your version is a typo in a sense, in that the entire quotient of the two sine terms should be "inside" the log in the integrand.

**ADDED:** *Leibniz does imply something...*

In the above integral (with $a=1$), denoted $H(p,q),$ using Leibniz differentiation under the integral sign gives the derivative w.r.t. $p$ as
$$H_p=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-2q}{(p-q \sin x)^2}$$
and the derivative w.r.t. $q$ as
$$H_q=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2p}{(p-q \sin x)^2}.$$
This implies that $H(p,q)$ satisfies
$$p\cdot H_p(p,q)+q \cdot H_q(p,q)=0. \tag{1}$$
This pde is satisfied by the actual value $\pi \arcsin(q/p).$ Of course the $\pi$ here could be replaced by another constant and $(1)$ would still hold, and from the symmetry $k \arcsin(p/q)$ would also solve $(1)$. I don't know much about pde but I tried a few other simple formulas for $H(p,q)$ and didn't get other solutions to $(1)$. [It may be a large class of functions for all I know.]

Comment: The "added" part is useless, as if $H(p,q)=w(p/q)$ for any function $w$ then $H$ satisfies pde $(1)$ above. [and the integral here can be written that way by division of top and bottom of the sine fraction by $q$].